# Release problems in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management

I would like to ask about the memory management problems in objective C. I am the green of the objective C. When I read some of the sample program from the Apple website, I saw a [XXX release]. I guess this statement is used to release the use of the variable. However, when I use this statement in my program, I got some problems. I used the NSLog() to display the content, but it cannot display the content, it shows some statement about the release.

does the objective C has the auto memory management just like java? or we need to care about the memory problems by the program.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Objective-C does have garbage collection ("auto memory management"), but only on the Mac.  It is not available on the iPhone.  However, [the rule of memory management](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html) is not that complicated.  It is:

If you were given an object via a method (or function) that contains the word `new`, `alloc`, `retain`, or `copy`, then you must either `release` the object or `autorelease` it.

That's pretty much it.  If you always follow this convention, then 99.999% of the time you're going to be OK.  The other 0.001% of the time, read the documentation (or ask us here on StackOverflow! :) ).

(I'll also add that anything the documentation says that contradicts this rule wins.)

Answer (score 2):

Read the [Memory Management Rules](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html). Just knowing those few simple rules will tell you all you need to know about memory management in Objective-C.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to call `release` on objects you `init`/`alloc` yourself or your instance variables in your class `dealloc` method.

Objective-C does have auto release pools.